# How to efficiently insert billions of data into mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, numpy, gis, geojson

Currently I have an array of 1e10 coordinates in a numpy array, in format like this:

```
[[-20.225869 1.1488514 47.007915]
[-19.585725 1.1527847 47.106827]
[-19.007616 1.0450604 41.686756]
[-19.277712 1.0455568 41.622501]
[-19.650136 1.0519722 41.848976]
......
]
```

each row is a point's coordinates (x, y, z).
And I hope to insert them into a mongodb database (GeoJSON). 
My current approach is like this:

```
for point in points:
    db.map.insert_one(
    {
        "loc": 
        {
            "x": np.float64(point[0]),
            "y": np.float64(point[1]),    
        }          
        "z": np.float64(point[2])
    }
)
```

And this process really costs a lot of time. 
I am wondering if there is some efficient approach I can do this? Should I turn to C++ for better performance?

Thank you very much.

Comment: have a look  at this for an option https://www.khalidalnajjar.com/insert-200-million-rows-into-mongodb-in-minutes/

Comment: create batches, for example 100 points at a time. Mongo can do bulk inserts. You'll save a lot of time. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/  and  http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html

Comment: bulk insert batches, try with different batch sizes

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for helping me, and my insersion performance has been improved a lot! (from 3.5h to 20min) 
Per [this Pymongo document](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html), 
first I have tried insert_many([point for point in POINTS]). It is efficient on 1e6 points, but it exit with code 137 or 9 (memory exceed) for 1e8 points.
Then I tried customize batch size as 1e7 and continue to use insert_many, but the performance did not improve (cannot tell the reason). 
FINALLY, Unordered Bulk Write in same document saved my life, and it can handle at least 1e8 points in 30 minites with out error.